# How to order by variable field?

Tags: django, model

I create a custom MultilingualCharField and I want order the instances by it, in the right language. I prefer to do so in the model (tell me if this wasn't a good idea), is it possible?

```
class Myclass(models.Model):
    name = MultilingualCharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    ...

def __str__(self):
    name_traslated={'name_it': self.name_it, 'name_en': self.name_en}
    name_verbose=_('name_it')
    return name_traslated[name_verbose]

class Meta:
    #name_traslated={'name_it': self.name_it, 'name_en': self.name_en}
    name_verbose=_('name_it')
    ordering = [name_verbose]
    #ordering = [name_traslated[name_verbose]]
```

`__str__` is working but `ordering` is not: it gives `TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): name_verbose`

My `MultilingualCharField` create two columns: `name_it` and `name_en` and I want to order the istances on one of these. If you need it here's the code (from Web Development with Django Cookbook):

```
class MultilingualCharField(models.CharField):

def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
    self._blank = kwargs.get("blank", False)
    self._editable = kwargs.get("editable", True)
    #super(MultilingualCharField, self).__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)
    super().__init__(verbose_name, **kwargs)

def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, virtual_only=False):
    # generate language specific fields dynamically
    if not cls._meta.abstract:
        for lang_code, lang_name in settings.LANGUAGES:
            if lang_code == settings.LANGUAGE_CODE:
                _blank = self._blank
            else:
                _blank = True
            localized_field = models.CharField(string_concat(
                self.verbose_name, " (%s)" % lang_code),
                name=self.name,
                primary_key=self.primary_key,
                max_length=self.max_length,
                unique=self.unique,
                blank=_blank,
                null=False,
                # we ignore the null argument!
                db_index=self.db_index,
                rel=self.rel,
                default=self.default or "",
                editable=self._editable,
                serialize=self.serialize,
                choices=self.choices,
                help_text=self.help_text,
                db_column=None,
                db_tablespace=self.db_tablespace
            )
            localized_field.contribute_to_class(cls, 
                "%s_%s" % (name, lang_code),)

    def translated_value(self):
        language = get_language()
        val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, language)]
        if not val:
            val = self.__dict__["%s_%s" % (name, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)]
            return val

    setattr(cls, name, property(translated_value))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a model with a field `name`. My custom `MultilingualCharField` create in the database a field for each language (`name_en`, `name_it` etc). I **don't** have a field `name` in the database, but only in the model.

So, here what I did (I think can be useful even if you don't use a custom field but a field for each language in the model):

In `mymodel.py`:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ordering = [_('name_it')]
```

This works in form etc but gives an error in admin (`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`), so here's my `Admin.py`:

```
class MyClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_ordering(self, request):
        if get_language_from_request(request)=='it':
            return ['name_it']
        else:
            return ['name_en']
```

If you find an error or a better way please tell me